# L2TP/IPSec VPN Connection

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, vpn, ipsec

On OS X, there's an option for L2TP/IPSec VPN in network connections where it lets you enter an IP Address, Username, Password, and Shared Secret.

I downloaded Strongswan in Ubuntu, but do not see any place to put a Shared Secret, Username, or Password. There are boxes to select a file for certificate and private key (I do not have these files nor do I know how to get them).

How can I just manually enter the information I need to connect over VPN?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem 2 month ago. I decided to contact Sergey Prochorov, autor of network manager plugin for l2tp. He answered me that "I'm now stop supporting l2tp plugin, since I just don't use it in my everyday life."

After many days I switched to Fedora. But unfortunately also in Fedora there is possible to connect only using terminal and some bash scripts. Network manager solution is not working too. I don't know about any Linux distribution with network manager L2tp PSK VPN support.

Finally - interesting is that under new Windows 10 is also a bug - there is impossible (interactively) to set Ipv4 and Ipv6 options for VPNs ;).

Answer (score 0):

*(see my full answser in https://askubuntu.com/a/891021/299951 - not tested though)*

- I can confirm, that the preshared-key STILL cannot be entered and I couldn't find a direct solution after one whole day of research
- there exists a [little docker container](https://github.com/ubergarm/l2tp-ipsec-vpn-client) for a vpn client with **preshared-key**