# l2tp client yakkety (16.10)

Tags: vpn, ipsec

Does anyone know if there is a l2tp-client for Yakkety? I've seen some post about installing on 16.04 and earlier but have not found something for 16.10.

Preferably using network-manager but anything is appriciated.

/Mike

Comment: `xl2tpd` is available for all releases.

Answer (score 0):

there is the **strongswan network manager**
`apt-get install strongswan network-manager-strongswan`

## The good part:

This will enable a new vpn option

[image]

## The bad part

There is no chance of providing **public-shared-key** if you need to use this for your setup

(This answer is related to: [I can't get any L2TP + IPSEC client to work on Ubuntu 14.04 with pre-shared key, can you?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643402/i-cant-get-any-l2tp-ipsec-client-to-work-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-pre-shared-key/891021#891021))

Answer (score 0):

network-manager-l2tp 1.2.8 packages for 17.04 (zesty), 16.04 (denial) and 14.04 (trusty) can be found here:

- https://launchpad.net/~nm-l2tp/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-l2tp

Ubuntu 17.10 and later include network-manager-l2tp in a default repository.